# MPC Protocol with Additions and Multiplications for FREE

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

Imagine an **MPC protocol** where both multiplications and additions come for free (2 round). The protocol works over **arithmetic circuits**, and the security setup is as relaxed as possible:

1. Semi-Honest.
2. Honest Majorities.

- Does such a protocol exist?
- If so, what would be the most restrictive security model, and maintain the 2 rounds?

Comment: How do you define "free"? Do you want the communication cost to be independent to the number of additions and multiplications? and require constant round complexity? Usually secret-sharing or GC-based MPC protocols don't have these properties, but you can probably achieve using FHE. The communication complexity would be proportional to the size of the input (plus the key switching keys which might be big). But FHE is much more expensive computationally.

Comment: @lamba. Thanks so much for your comment. Indeed, free in this case means, round complexity. I am aware of impossibility results stating that I need at least 2 rounds.